# Fetch ID from separate table in SQL

Tags: java, sql, intellij-idea, derby

I have two tables, one called Member:

```
 NAME  |   PERSONALNUMBER  |               ID  |  
LUDDE  |       9409251171  |                1  |
```

and one called Boats:

```
       TYPE  |           LENGTH  |         MEMBERID  |  
Motorsailer  |            100.0  |             null  |
```

I want to fetch the `ID` from member and store it in `MEMBERID` in Boats.

Right now I try getting the ID from a specific member by doing this:

```
public void createBoat(Boat boat, Member member) {
    try {
        connection.createStatement().execute("Insert into BOAT (Type, Length) values " + boat.toString());
        connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT ID FROM MEMBER WHERE NAME LIKE " + "'" + member.getName() + "'" );
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting null instead of any real data.

Comment: sorry, but I can't see you're getting 'null'. You can help people to reproduce your problem by adding more code or maybe you can  add some console output.

Comment: you don't do anything with the result of executeQuery().

Comment: Also. If you use the 'LIKE' function, don't forget to add the percentage symbols, as such: "SELECT ID FROM MEMBER WHERE NAME LIKE " + "'%" + member.getName() + "%'".  Otherwise you might as well just use the equals operator '='

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select particular id from `Member` table using select statement. Then use that `member id` in insert statement of `Boats` table.

You can use following. You may need to do small modification. I dont know what is the length of boat so i am using 100 as length. Also i'm assuming member id is an integer

```
public void createBoat(Boat boat, Member member) {
    try {

        ResultSet rs=connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT ID FROM MEMBER WHERE NAME =" + "'" + member.getName() + "'");
        while(rs.next()){
            int memberId=rs.getInt("ID");
            connection.createStatement().execute("Insert into BOAT (Type, Length,MEMBERID) values (" + boat.toString() ",100,"+memberId+" )");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```